# How to count each type/kind of objects from a Sequence of mixed objects by Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a Sequence of **Color** objects, say `Seq[Color]`

```
[
    {
        "color": "red"
    },
    {
        "color": "yellow"
    },
    {
        "color": "yellow"
    },
    {
        "color": "white"
    }
]
```

What I want to get is the count of each color, as an object, say **ColorCount**, like below

```
{
    "red": 1,
    "yellow": 2,
    "white": 1
}
```

Now what I can think of is something like below. I wonder if there a more elegant way of dealing with it.

```
val redCount = colors.count( e => e.color == 'red') 
val yellowCount = colors.count( e => e.color == 'yellow') 
val whiteCount = colors.count( e => e.color == 'white') 

val colorCount = ColorCount(redCount, yellowCount, whiteCount)
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming **Color** is defined like this:

```
sealed trait Color
object Color {
  final case object Red extends Color
  final case object Yellow extends Color
  final case object White extends Color
}
```

And **ColorCount** like this:

```
final case class ColorCount(redCount: Int, yellowCount: Int, whiteCount: Int)
```

And you have a **List** of **Colors** *(`val colors: List[Color] = ???`)*.
Then, you can do this in a one go by using `groupBy`

```
// For 2.12-
val counts = colors.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)
// For 2.13+
val counts = colors.groupMapReduce(identity)(_ => 1)(_ + _)
```

And finally transform those `counts` into a **ColorCount**.

```
val result = ColorCount(
  redCount = counts.getOrElse(key = Color.Red, default = 0),
  yellowCount = counts.getOrElse(key = Color.Yellow, default = 0),
  whiteCount = counts.getOrElse(key = Color.White, default = 0),
)
```